# how to defined event e while using it with .on()

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am using .on() to bind touch event with element ,but i am getting error e is not defined . what to do ?i tried writing event e inside brackets but it is not working .

```
$("#myImageFlow ").on('click touchstart',".sliderImage",abc);
//custom function handler for event                  
function abc(){

 e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();

console.log('has no method ...................'+e);
```

how to define event variable , because i am not calling function  with ()??

Comment: Can you not change your function to be `function abc(e){`

Answer (score 4):

`abc` is the event handler, so you need to use `function abc(e){}`

```
$("#myImageFlow ").on('click touchstart', ".sliderImage", abc);
//custom function handler for event                  
function abc(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('has no method ...................' + e);
}
```

- http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @anderssonola , what do you mean by _e is undefined_ ?

Comment: @pXL passing e to function touchstart stops working , is ther any way to store in variable or something?

Comment: @simmisimmi have you tried removing `e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();`.

Comment: @simmisimmi are you sure you are not calling `abc()` from somewhere else.

Comment: @pXl sorry missed your using callback for .on()

Comment: @pXL touch only works if i get something error in console , for example when i was getting e not defined then it was workin or else i will say print anything in console which is not defined then touch works

Comment: @simmisimmi that is really strange !

Answer (score 2):

Define `e` as an argument:

```
function abc(e){
    if(typeof(e) != "undefined" && e.type == "click"){ // only call stopPropagation and preventDefault on click events
        e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
    }

    console.log('has no method ...................'+e);
}
```

Alternatively you can selectively pass the argument:

```
$("#myImageFlow ")
    .on('click',".sliderImage", function(e){
        abc(e);
    })
    .on('touchstart',".sliderImage", function(){
        abc();
    });
```

Comment: passing e to function touchstart stops working , is ther any way to store in variable or something? –

Comment: See my edit, you can add a condition so that `e` is only used for `click` events

Comment: i cant pass any thing to function as an argument .. if i do so my touch stps working on tablet

Comment: See my second example, you can define a separate handler for click and touchstart by chaining the `on`.

Answer (score 1):

Your reference function will get event as a parameter:-

```
function abc(e){

 e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();

console.log('has no method ...................'+e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion

```
$("#myImageFlow ").on('click touchstart',".sliderImage", function(event){
  alert(event);
});
```